# Ошибка при компиляции в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При компиляции вылазит такая ошибка, думал из за кодировки, все перепробывал не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снимается, затупил, надо было использовать Paths.get()